# Spark streaming job in scala doesn't run on Airflow

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I usually work with Pyspark but I had to deal with a spark streaming job written in Scala. I am running the spark-submit on EMR directly it works but running the same through Airflow throws me the following error. I don't even to where to start debugging the issue. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:226)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.runDriver(ApplicationMaster.scala:468)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.org$apache$spark$deploy$yarn$ApplicationMaster$$runImpl(ApplicationMaster.scala:305)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(ApplicationMaster.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$run$1.apply(ApplicationMaster.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$run$1.apply(ApplicationMaster.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$3.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:779)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1844)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.doAsUser(ApplicationMaster.scala:778)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:803)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.main(ApplicationMaster.scala)
Caused by: com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$IO: available_application.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=log4j-yarn.properties: java.io.FileNotFoundException: available_application.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=log4j-yarn.properties (No such file or directory)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parseable.parseValue(Parseable.java:183)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parseable.parseValue(Parseable.java:170)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parseable.parse(Parseable.java:227)
    at com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory.parseFile(ConfigFactory.java:595)
    at com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory.loadDefaultConfig(ConfigFactory.java:244)
    at com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory.access$000(ConfigFactory.java:38)
    at com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory$1.call(ConfigFactory.java:378)
    at com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory$1.call(ConfigFactory.java:375)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.ConfigImpl$LoaderCache.getOrElseUpdate(ConfigImpl.java:58)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.ConfigImpl.computeCachedConfig(ConfigImpl.java:86)
    at com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory.load(ConfigFactory.java:375)
    at com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory.load(ConfigFactory.java:299)
    at com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory.load(ConfigFactory.java:288)
    at com.nike.tdp.AvailabilityKafkaEvents$.main(AvailabilityKafkaEvents.scala:101)
    at com.nike.tdp.AvailabilityKafkaEvents.main(AvailabilityKafkaEvents.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:684)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: available_application.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=log4j-yarn.properties (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parseable$ParseableFile.reader(Parseable.java:512)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parseable.rawParseValue(Parseable.java:193)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parseable.parseValue(Parseable.java:176)
    ... 19 more
22/10/26 19:14:02 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
```

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: available_application.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=log4j-yarn.properties

is the main piece of information in the error you've shown.

It looks like you've made a typo in the parameters for running the app and `available_application.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=log4j-yarn.properties` is interpreted as the configuration file name instead of only `available_application.properties` (I assume).

Check the parameters used to run your app, maybe quotes in wrong place or missing? Maybe extra whitespace? ...

Comment: thanks a lot. I changed these lines in my spark-submit from ```--conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="-Dconfig.file= available_application.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=log4j-yarn.properties"``` to ```--conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="-Dconfig.file= available_application.properties" --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j-yarn.properties"``` . Now I am getting com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'prod' even when I run on EMR directly it fails.

Comment: Does your conf file contains such setting `prod` or `prod.xxx`?

Comment: I have a available_application.properties file that has prod.xxx